# wpa2-psk aes hacking with android

Tags: android, wpa2, wpa2-psk

I have a [digisol HR3400](http://smartlink.co.in/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2014/09/How-to-Configure-in-PPPoE-DSL-DG-HR3400.pdf) router, I want to prevent it from being hacked.

Can I use **wpa2-psk aes** to prevent hacking by Android apps like andro dumper or wpa tester?

Comment: please post links to the things you are talking about

Comment: Maybe a better way to ask this question is will wpa2-psk aes be sufficiant to fend off Andro Dumper and WPA Tester? A little more to the point and less broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPA2 AES is the best encryption you can choose right now for your wireless network. You should put a large and strong password to avoid bruteforce attacks. The password should container letters (uppercase and lowercase), numbers, symbols. You can set it from 8 to 63 digits. The more larger, more difficult to crack using bruteforce. Of course, the password must not be included on any dictionary, so must be something "invented".

If you want to be secure you still should perform an important task. You must disable WPS if your access point has it enabled. With this feature enabled an alternative auth can be performed using a 8 digit pin that can be easily bruteforced. And after success doing this, your WPA2 password is revealed (no matter how large and strong is). So disable WPS is mandatory.

Androdummper, and that kind of tools are taking advantage of WPS. So if you disable it, you are more protected.